# adding index in rails

Tags: activerecord, rake

I

I have added has_many and belongs_to after running rake db:migrate. I added these associations and again rake db:migrate. No index was generated. Can you please tell me why is that?

Below are my associations

class Developer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :evaluations
  has_many :final_scores
  belongs_to :supervisor
end

class Evaluation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :developer
  belongs_to :supervisor
 end

class FinalScore < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :developer
end

class Supervisor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :developers
  has_many :evaluations :through => :developers
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the official rails guide on this subject: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

There you can see that you need to change the generated migration file and add the field by yourself.

Comment: Oh ok..I was thinking the index:true and " add index" comes up in the Create table when you do the associations.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog](http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/rails-add-has-many-association-to-existing-model/) helps to understand better. You may missed out something in migration file.